# Qiskit: Transpilation and the CircuitSampler

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, transpile

I am using Qiskit's `opflow` and its `CircuitSampler` to evaluate matrix elements / expectation values. Now, going beyond `statevector` and simple `qasm` simulations, I want to introduce noise of a real device, specify qubit-connectivity (`coupling_map`), and choose which physical qubits the logical qubits of my circuit are mapped to (`initial_layout`). This is all specified in a `QuantumInstance` which is then passed to the `CircuitSampler`,

```
result = CircuitSampler(QuantumInstance).convert(operator).eval()
```

How do all these specifications for transpilation translate through the `CircuitSampler` and into the final output? I.e., does `CircuitSampler` transpile the circuits inside, e.g., `ListOp` before sampling? And how can I check which *physical qubits* the logical ones were mapped to during transpilation?

I am confused by [this sentence in the documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.converters.CircuitSampler.html?highlight=circuitsampler#qiskit.opflow.converters.CircuitSampler):

> The CircuitSampler aggressively caches transpiled circuits to handle re-parameterization of the same circuit efficiently.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This post contains a few questions,  so let's first recap the steps the circuit sampler goes through (you can also check out the [source code here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/77da2b5668637ad878d2773dadc79530f82b3459/qiskit/opflow/converters/circuit_sampler.py#L144)), before answering your questions.

#### How the Circuit Sampler works

Provided with a backend/quantum instance and an operator expression, the job of the circuit sampler is to execute all circuits in the operator expression and replace them by the circuit result. Imagine you have an operator expression consisting of an operator measurement composed with a circuit-state:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit.h(0)

hamiltonian = X + Z

expr = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True).compose(state)
print(expr)
# prints:
# ComposedOp([
#   OperatorMeasurement(1.0 * X
#   + 1.0 * Z),
#   CircuitStateFn(
#        ┌───┐
#   q_0: ┤ H ├
#        └───┘
#   )
# ])
```

If you then apply the circuit sampler (e.g. with a statevector simulator as backend)

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
sampler = CircuitSampler(backend) 
sampled = sampler.convert(expr)
print(sampled)
# prints:
# ComposedOp([
#   OperatorMeasurement(1.0 * X
#   + 1.0 * Z),
#   VectorStateFn(Statevector([0.70710678+0.j, 0.70710678+0.j], dims=(2,)))
# ])
```

then `sampled` is the same as `expr` but the circuit-state has been replaced with a vector-state.

To do that, the circuit sampler goes through the following steps:

1. Extract all circuits from the operator expression (and cache them)
2. Transpile all circuits (and cache them)
3. Execute all circuits with the provided quantum instance
4. Replace the original circuit-states with the results

#### Your questions

So to answer your questions above:

> How do all these specifications for transpilation translate through the CircuitSampler and into the final output?

Yes, the circuit sampler transpiles the circuits according to the specifications
in the quantum instance.

> And how can I check which physical qubits the logical ones were mapped to during transpilation?

There is no nice way to check what the transpiled circuits look like. Ideally you would just transpile the circuits manually with the quantum instance since the circuit sampler's purpose is only the execution. However, you could access the cache (but that's not officially supported behavior):

```
last_cache = list(sampler._cached_ops.values())[-1]
transpiled_circs = last_cache.transpiled_circ_cache
```

> I am confused by this sentence in the documentation:
>
> > The CircuitSampler aggressively caches transpiled circuits to handle re-parameterization of the same circuit efficiently.

We often have the use case where we want to execute the same circuit many times but with different parameter values in the qubit gates. If we only change the parameter values, we can transpile a "template" and only assign the values afterwards. Since transpilation is expensive, this can save a lot of time.

As pointed out above in the circuit sampler steps, the circuits sampler caches circuits at different points and tries to re-use already transpiled circuits to avoid the expensive transpilation.

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive answer! Manually transpiled circuits would not be re-transpiled by the `CircuitSampler`?

Comment: Yes, they would, but re-transpiling already transpiled circuits is very cheap since they are already in the correct basis gate set and optimized.

Comment: @Cryoris How can I send multiple circuits through the CircuitSampler? I am calculating expectation values for VQE and I want all of my circuits for each iteration sent to the IBMQ simultaneously to reduce queue times. I tried ```sampler = CircuitSampler(q_instance).convert(expectation)``` where ```expectation``` is a list but I receive a "'list' object has no attribute 'to_circuit_op'" error.

Comment: If you wrap the list into a `ListOp` it should work.

Comment: @Cryoris, You mentioned that "We often have the use case where we want to execute the same circuit many times but with different parameter values in the qubit gates." In my case, I have a loop which uses ```CircuitSampler```, sends it to the backend, computes a cost function from output, and repeats. For each iteration after the first, will ```CircuitSampler``` check the cache to reduce transpilation time?

Comment: Only if you pass the parameters as the second argument in `CircuitSampler.convert`, otherwise it won't be able to recognize that it has seen a similar circuit before already.